# What is a good and quick introduction to the theory of convergence of Riemannian manifolds ?

Tags: reference-request

Hello, what can be a good yet quick introduction to the theory of convergence of Riemannian manifolds ? You can list all the references with your opinions. I know in Peter Petersen's book, he has a chapter on it, but I guess it is probably not that quick . Also is there a paper/book discussing the convergence of hyperbolic manifolds ?

Thank you !

Comment: Question should be community wiki

Comment: I guess it depends on exactly what you're looking for.  I think the first theorem about limits of Riemannian manifolds is actually a statement about metric spaces, namely that Gromov-Hausdorff convergence preserves curvature bounds.  I think the best reference for Gromov-Hausdorff limits (which also discusses curvature bounds in this context) is "A Course in Metric Geometry" by Burago, Burago, and Ivanov.

Comment: The questions that arise in my study is like hyperbolic surfaces with n boundary components converging to the hyperbolic surface with n cusps, where the lengths of the boundary compone ts are going to zero.Here n is a fixed number >= 3. 